# Galois theory homomorphisms inequality

Tags: field-theory

I'm working through a proof and don't get a part of it.
Here we have a finite field extension $L/K$ and any other extension $M/K.$
We are assuming $K\subset K(\alpha )\subset L.$

We have a map $\rho : \text{Hom}_K (L, M) \rightarrow \text{Hom}_K (K(\alpha ), M), \Phi \mapsto \Phi |_{K(\alpha )}.$

The part I don't understand is how we can view $\rho ^{-1} (\phi ) $ as the set of $K(\alpha )-$homomorphisms from $L$ to $M$.
Why if $\Phi \in \rho^{-1}(\phi )$ does $\Phi $ have to fix $K(\alpha)$? I understand it must fix $K$ but where does the fixing the whole of $K(\alpha )$ come from?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by $\phi$.

Comment: $\phi $ is in $\text{Hom}_K(L,M) $ and I'm talking about the preimage of $\phi $ under $\rho $

Comment: If $L$ and $M$ are abstract field extensions of $K$, then there is no reason $M$ should contain $K(\alpha)$, so it might not be meaningful to ask whether a $K$-homomorphism $\Phi:L\to M$ fixes $K(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi \in \mathrm{Hom}_K(K(\alpha),M)$. Then we can view $K(\alpha)$ as a subfield of $M$ via $\phi$. If we do that, then for a homomorphism $\Phi:L \to M$, it fixes $K(\alpha)$ if and only if the restriction of $\Phi$ to $K(\alpha)$ agrees with $\phi$, i.e. $\Phi \in \rho^{-1}(\phi)$.

To see this let $\Phi \in \mathrm{Hom}_K(L,M)$. Then for every $x \in K(\alpha)$, we have $\Phi(x)=x$ if and only if $\Phi(x)=\phi(x)$, because we chose to embed $K(\alpha)$ into $M$ via $\phi$. Thus we get that $\Phi$ fixes $K(\alpha)$ if and only if $\Phi|_{K(\alpha)}=\rho(\Phi)=\phi$